# Example of a non finitely generated Structure Sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Does there exist an affine algebraic variety $X \subset \mathbb{A^n}$ and an open subset $U \subset X$ such that the algebra $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ is not finitely generated?